# Flip Animation in Android for two views

Tags: android

**Can anybody tell me how to do this **

I am new in android.I wanted to create animations for below :

I have two views : 1.Image drawn by canvas (assume DrawView) & 2. TextView

I added rotation to DrawView from -90 to 90 (works like its wiping screen from bottom left corner to bottom right corner in circular motion)

Now I want to show TextView just like DrawView image is uncovering Textview.

I think Drawview should act like foreground view and textView like background .

I am adding image for better explaination!

Image Link : 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8DGjJBt0XQ_TVBtS0lidUFhZzA/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used two views in frame layout.

made Image drawn by canvas (assume DrawView) as front view .
using DrawView.bringToFront();

Worked !